# Why does Betelgeuse freak out at the presence of a "lesser spirit" in episode 22?

Tags: re-zero

The moment I'm talking about is episode 22 of the anime when he's possessing the body of a female cult member, and a little red ball comes swirling by.

Is there any additional significance to it that I'm not aware of or just Betelgeuse being crazy?

Watching the next episode makes me better aware of the fact Julius was keeping an eye on Subaru. However I assume there's little Julius/Ia could have done to help (or he would've done that already considering the rather dire lifethreatening situation Subaru was, being crushed into the tree).

Comment: I suspect that the nature of Betelgeuse's presence and possession of bodies is based on mechanics of these spirits. So if a spirit of evil/sin/chaos meets a spirit of good/order, it's potentially very bad news for them both. But in this case the good spirit is self-sufficient, and Betelgeuse's spirit is at a disadvantage somehow because it has to possess a body to manifest itself. Just my guess. I think we might see it explained in the later episodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Betelgeuse die he became some sort of quasi spirit himself allowing him to possess those who are spirit compatible or lacking in sanity, in this case the fingers , Subaru and skip by the anime, Julius (The guy got his own issue).

Julius however cannot be possessed due to having six guardian spirits. This did not allow him to choose Julius as a host after the last of the fingers were eliminated but instead tried for the next best thing which is Subaru. if he did tried to possessed Julius. Betelgeuse must fight against the other six spirits and that can cause severe pain to the mind of the host which may cause him to be ejected and die for real.

Subaru to was having the same problem like Betelgeuse but we saw it much clearly, severe headache when the spirit try to cleanse him of Ram illusion

Even when Subaru has IA ,Julius lesser fire spirit to help him Subaru is not the true pact wielder of the spirit making him vulnerable to possession.

But still wanting Julius as a body due to his more powerful body Subaru was taken hostage to try to get Julius to get rid of his pact , not wanting Julius his friend (and himself)  getting possessed and wreaking havoc he ask to be killed by Felix . Felix in turn ruin Subaru Gate causing his blood to boil (see episode 5 death) and Julius tearfully end his life for that loop.